# TOR Control Protocol from Perl

Tags: perl, sockets, controls, tor

I am trying to basically make a `signal newnym` call via [Tor control protocol](https://svn.torproject.org/svn/torctl/trunk/doc/howto.txt) bound to an internal port. Just for testing I am trying without any auth field at the moment.

In telnet, if I just call `AUTHENTICATE` I get authenticated and can then proceed to signal calls.

In perl using *both* [IO::Socket](http://p3rl.org/IO%3a%3aSocket), and [Socket](http://p3rl.org/Socket) `send` methods I end up with this error:

> 551 Invalid quoted string.  You need to put the password in double quotes.

A sample call I am using in IO::Socket would look approximately like this:

```
print "SIG-TOR:Connecting...";

my $TORSOCK = new IO::Socket::INET(
    PeerAddr => $torcont,
    PeerPort => $torconp,
    Proto    => 'tcp'
);
$TORSOCK or die "no socket :$!";

print "OK!\n";

print "SIG-TOR:authenticating...";

print $TORSOCK $torauth;

while (<$TORSOCK>) {
    print $_;
}

print "OK!\n";
sleep(1);
```

Comment: What is the value of `$torauth`?

Answer (score 1):

From

> 551 Invalid quoted string. You need to put the password in double quotes.

I would infer the need for

```
print $TORSOCK '"', $torauth, '"';
```

But you need to be **certain** what is in $torauth.